# Issue with my var getting undefined

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a reverse function to the String type in javascript. My code is like

```
String.prototype.reverse = function () {
    var s = "";
    for(var i=this.length;i>=0;i--){
            s+=this[i];
    }
    return s;
}
```

When I try to use it on for example like `"test".reverse();`

instead of giving **"tset"** it's giving **"undefinedtset"**

I am setting the variable like `var s = ""`; inside the function, still undefined is coming. Why is it so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to change `var i=this.length` to `var i=this.length-1`, because an array starts at position 0 :

```
String.prototype.reverse = function () {
    var s = "";
    for(var i=this.length-1;i>=0;i--){
            s+=this[i];
    }
    return s;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`this.length` gives you `4` (4 letters in `test` word) and you start iterating from `4` to `0`.

The problem is that nothing exists under `4` index (your letters are stored in `0-3` positions).

Try with:

```
for (var i = this.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    s += this[i];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason why your code isn't working has been answered by the others already, but if you want a shorter version of the reverse, you can do it like this:

```js
String.prototype.reverse = function(){
  return this.split('').reverse().join('');
}

console.log('Hello World'.reverse())
```